# Spring Security Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, When I add @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")  on service layer class which is injected into UserDetailService implementation Class, I get an error "This object has already been built."  If I apply method security,on any other service class they work fine.

Part of Stack trace

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiHttpSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.CustomUserDetailsService org.autoever.ess.config.MultiHttpSecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.service.UserMgmt org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.userMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multiHttpSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.CustomUserDetailsService org.autoever.ess.config.MultiHttpSecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.service.UserMgmt org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.userMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer.init(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:135)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer.init(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:125)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:236)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:178)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
        at org.autoever.ess.config.MultiHttpSecurityConfig$ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a13c97a8.init(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:98)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6b4b216.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6b4b216$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9d53fd23.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6b4b216.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.CustomUserDetailsService org.autoever.ess.config.MultiHttpSecurityConfig.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.service.UserMgmt org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.userMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 61 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.service.UserMgmt org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.userMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 63 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.autoever.ess.sy.service.UserMgmt org.autoever.ess.sy.repository.impl.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.userMgmt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 74 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMgmt' defined in file [D:\workspace\luna\haei\ess\target\classes\org\autoever\ess\sy\service\UserMgmt.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 76 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.getAdvice(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.isAspectJAdvice(AspectJProxyUtils.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.makeAdvisorChainAspectJCapableIfNecessary(AspectJProxyUtils.java:49)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.extendAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        ... 85 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 104 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:42)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:247)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae29a4ef.CGLIB$methodSecurityInterceptor$6(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae29a4ef$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d530a331.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae29a4ef.methodSecurityInterceptor(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 105 more
```

My Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {     
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/sy/users/requestPassword").permitAll();
            http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()).accessDeniedHandler(new RestAccessDeniedHandler()).and().csrf().disable();
        }
    } 

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {           
            String[] unsecuredResources = { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/fonts/**" };
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(unsecuredResources);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            String[] unSecuredUrls = { "login.html", "/login", "/home", "/appPwd.html", "/partials/pwdRequest.html" };
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(unSecuredUrls).permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler).defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).and().logout().permitAll();
        }
    }  
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My  Custom interface extending UserDetailsService

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {

}
```

UserDetailsService  Implementation

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements CustomUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserMgmt userMgmt;       

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        MyUserDetails user = userMgmt.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName " + username + " not found");
        }        
        return user;
    }
}
```

and UserMgmt

```
@Service
public class UserMgmt {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;


    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_PI_BAS_CREATE')")
    @Transactional
    public MyUserDetails create(MyUserDetails item) {
    //Create logic
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like there may be an issue here: http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll(). See this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2726)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any  to initialize your code? 
You might be initializing twice due to configuration.

Spring boot does some funky stuff automatically for you...
Which actually stopped me from using it.
I think it does this bit for you automatically

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
```

Try taking it out of your (MultiHttpSecurityConfig)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is due to some cyclic dependency somewhere. Maybe if we clean up the code a little bit it would be easier to debug.

First of all I would change the way you autowire your dependencies. Basically you don't exactly know when these dependencies get autowired. But we can make it better by declaring them as mandatory dependencies, meaning, it will not be possible to instantiate any of the services if their dependencies are not autowired first.
You can do that by declaring your dependencies as constructor parameters.

```
public class UserMgmt {
    private final UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    //@Autowired depending on your Spring version, you might need it
    public UserMgm (UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository){
       this.userDetailsRepository = userDetailsRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

You can adapt the other classe as well (CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl and MultiHttpSecurityConfig).

Then, I would change the way you declare your services/components to be declared from a config class instead. That way we would have more control over when they should be created. 
So instead of using the `@Service` annotation. I would declare the services like so:

```
@Configuration
public class UserManagementConfig {

   @Bean
   public UserMgmt userMgmt(@Autowired UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository){
       return new UserMgmt(userDetailsRepository);
   }

   @Bean
   public CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService (@Autowired UserMgmt userMgmt) {
       return new CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl(userMgmt);
   }
}
```

Please let us know if you still get the error so we can take a look into it.